# POST or GET React An idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, get

my question and quite simple, what is the best solution.

The context, I have an array that contains several objects.

The 1st solution and the following, is it better to POST only the elements that I need (ie not all the elements)

The 2nd solution, rather post the whole table and make a get to sort the elements that I need

do you have an idea what is the easiest to do?

Thank you Neff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your question may seem a little ambiguous. There are a few things to clarify, for example the usage of this `POST` method. However, here is my solution to my best understanding:

Assuming that the term "best" means the overall optimal option, I believe that you should always use the first solution since it benefits **both** the user and server. Sending minimal data packets reduces the need of bandwidth, in this case benefiting both the user and server. It also helps the server to get things done quicker, it is rather more beneficial for lightweight processing to be done in order for the server to free up CPU for other operations, i.e. handling more requests.

Though results may vary depending on individual need, this is my overall insight into the topic. Glad to answer your question.